# Migrating from Google contacts to People API. Tips on building it for Java?

Tags: java, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I have a Java desktop application that uses the Google Contacts API.  Looks like I need to switch over to using the Google People API now.  My current environment is Eclipse and it just includes all the needed APIs as jar files which I downloaded years ago.  Looking at the Contacts API migration guide and developer guide for Google Java API, I only see info for building the API with Maven or Gradle.  Is there anywhere I can just download the API as a jar file?

Thanks.
Eric S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you look at the guide for installing using maven, it should give you the antifact name. If you then google "maven download" antifact name, you should get a link to maven central where you can download the jar files from.

Or you can convert your project to using maven. Maven is supported by eclipse, so eclipse does have support for converting projects to use maven, and then you can use the maven install guide. (Remember to backup your project setup file, if they are not under version control)